# Selecting Some Columns and a Max Value of A specific Column From Spark Dataset

Tags: java, apache-spark, dataset, apache-spark-sql

Hi I have a JAVA spark Dataset when I give `dataset.show();`
gives below OutPut.

```
Col1    col2    rowNum

obj1    item1    1
obj1    item2    2
obj1    item3    3
obj2    item1    4
obj2    item3    5
obj3    item4    6
```

Of the Same Dataset, I want to get below output,

```
Col1    max(rownum)

obj1    3
obj2    5
obj3    6
```

I'm totally new to JAVA spark, Can anyone help me to get the above output from the same Dataset, and the return the last **max(rownum)** that is **6** in the above case.

Answer (score 1):

The below code would give the required output:

```
SparkSession s=SparkSession.builder().appName("Stack Overflow Example test").master("local[*]").getOrCreate();
DataFrameReader read=s.read();
Dataset<Row> resp=read.option("header","true").csv("D://test.csv");
Dataset<Row> withColumn = resp.withColumn("rowNum", resp.col("rowNum").cast("long"));
Dataset<Row> orderBy = withColumn.orderBy(resp.col("Col1"));
orderBy.groupBy(resp.col("Col1")).max("rowNum").show();
```

**Output:**

```
+----+-----------+
|Col1|max(rowNum)|
+----+-----------+
|obj1|          3|
|obj2|          5|
|obj3|          6|
+----+-----------+
```

I have used to header information, to ensure we get the schema.

Here the casting needs to be done for the `rowNum` column to either Integer or Long.
The ordering , followed by a group by to get the maximum value can be performed following that.

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty simple use case, so I can give you some tips. Try using the DataSet Java documentation:
https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/java/index.html?org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.html

You want to use the `groupBy` function to group rows by `Col1`. You'll be returned a RelationalGroupedDataset: https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/java/index.html?org/apache/spark/sql/RelationalGroupedDataset.html

You can use the `max` function to aggregate based on whatever columns you choose. Let me know if you have trouble with this.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/18907896)

Comment: @pirho even if the link changes, the docs for Dataset and RelationalGroupedDataset should be incredibly easy to find...The essentials are included in the answer -> "groupBy" and "max" from the corresponding APIs....no offense to the OP (everyone starts off somewhere!) but this is an incredibly basic question, so probably better to teach them where to look rather than to give them the one line answer.

Answer (score 0):

in Java

```java
String input = "C://Users//U6048715//Desktop//test.csv";                
// create new spark Session
SparkSession spark = SparkSession.builder().master("local[2]").appName("pivot Table").getOrCreate()
// loading file data                
Dataset<Row> file = spark.read().format("csv").option("header","true").load(input);

// creating view 
file.createTempView("tempTable");                   

Dataset<Row> result = spark.sql(" select col1 , max(row) from tempTable group by col1");                
result.show();
```